# Flutter: How to move TextField characer counter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, textfield, maxlength

The title sums up the question pretty well. I have a `TextField` with a `maxLength: 250` and this is what it looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to put the counter somewhere else? Optimally to the left of the send button, but otherwise maybe just above and on the left of the `TextField`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Probably not necessary, but here's my code:

```
TextField(
              controller: inputTextEditingController,
              focusNode: inputFocusNode,
              style: TextStyle(color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.green : Colors.blue, height: 0.8),
              maxLength: 250,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 0, 15),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.green : Colors.blue),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: _handleSubmitted,
                    icon: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.send,
                          color: inputFocusNode.hasFocus
                              ? Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.green : Colors.blue
                              : Colors.black54),
                    ),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Say something!",
                  hintStyle: inputFocusNode.hasFocus
                      ? TextStyle(color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.green : Colors.blue, fontSize: 16)
                      : TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)),
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to build and pass your own counter as a buildCounter parameter of a TextField Widget.

```dart
TextField(
  maxLength: 250,
  buildCounter: (_, {currentLength, maxLength, isFocused}) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
    child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(currentLength.toString() + "/" + maxLength.toString())),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  child: new TextField(
                  style: BurmeseUtil.textStyle(context),
                  controller: txtController,
                  maxLength: 1500,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Use decoration in TextField.Add counterText:' '
Good luck