# Flutter 2: Remove margin between a textfield and its maxlength

Tags: flutter, textfield

My problem is that I can't find how to remove the margin between a textfield and its maxlength display.

So here what I have:

[image]

[image]

Here what I would like to have:

[image]

Here the code I have:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 15,
        horizontal: 15
    ),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.grey,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        const Radius.circular(4),
      ),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        const Radius.circular(4),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  maxLength: 50,
);
```

Could you please help me to resolve my problem?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63484406/16688813).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to move TextField characer counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019207/flutter-how-to-move-textfield-characer-counter)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't solve the problem, I have updated the question to more highlight the problem. It does not come from the maxlength, because the padding and margin is .zero.

Comment: did you try with `buildCounter`?

Comment: Yes and as you can see the new picture this is the container of the buildCounter. To be sure I have put the margin at  `margin: EdgeInsets.zero,` to preshot any question.

Comment: So it still doesn't work